# How to send additional data in ajax request along with formData

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony, twig

I have a following ajax request `onChange` of file input value.

```
$(':file').change(function(){
        var file = this.files[0];

        var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);

        var id= $(this).attr('data-post-id'); // What I want to send additionaly to file

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/bghitn/web/app_dev.php/image/upload",           
            type: 'POST',           
            xhr: function() { 
                var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();

                if(myXhr.upload){ 
                    myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false);
                }
                return myXhr;
            },
            success: completeHandler,
            data: formData,
            data:{id:id}, // what is actually not working
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });        
    });
```

I am adding an attribute to the html tag that includes an `id` that I wish to send along with file related data.

```
<input type="file" name="img" data-post-id="{{entity.id}}" />
```

I use PHP under Symfony2 like:

```
  if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            $image = $request->files->get('img');

}
```

I need an equivalent way to get also the id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass it through url,

```
$(':file').change(function(){
        var file = this.files[0];

        var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);

        var id= $(this).attr('data-post-id'); // What I want to send additionnaly to file

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/bghitn/web/app_dev.php/image/upload?id="+id,
            //...........................................................^....

            type: 'POST',           
            xhr: function() { 
                var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();

                if(myXhr.upload){ 
                    myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false);
                }
                return myXhr;
            },
            success: completeHandler,
            data: formData,

            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });        
    });
```

Or you can use `append` method to add `id`

```
$(':file').change(function(){
        var file = this.files[0];

        var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
        formData.append("id",id);
        //...............^.......
        var id= $(this).attr('data-post-id'); // What I want to send additionnaly to file

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/bghitn/web/app_dev.php/image/upload?",


            type: 'POST',           
            xhr: function() { 
                var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();

                if(myXhr.upload){ 
                    myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false);
                }
                return myXhr;
            },
            success: completeHandler,
            data: formData,

            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });        
    });
```

Comment: I thank you for your time. It is a good idea but what about security using this approach?

Comment: try the second method

Comment: Thank you for your time Pranav, I will test the second approach and feedback.

Comment: how to get the appended data in php side?

Answer (score 1):

Just try this,

```
    data:{'id':id,
          'formdata':formData,
},
```

Comment: I thank you for your time. However, I didn't understand your answer. I need formData to be sent, why to remove it then.

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces I have updated my answer. Please check it.

Comment: ok , this is what I am testing now. I will combe back to feedback. thank you

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces Any errors in console or didn't got the `id` at server side ?

Comment: Thank you I have no issue now using the append method as described in the accepted answer. thanks again for your time

Answer (score 0):

You don't send data twice. Send inthis format :

```
data: {
  formData : formData,
  id:id
},
```

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces okay hope it helps !

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces oh. can you tell me the issues that you are facing?

Comment: Thank you I have no issue now using the append method as described in the accepted answer. thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
function AjaxRequests($url,$content_type,$target_id,$additional_data) {
                
        if ($additional_data != '') {
            $additional_data = '&'+$additional_data;
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $url,
            data: "ajaxrequest="+$content_type+$additional_data,
            success: function($response){
                $($target_id).html($response)
            }
        })
    
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).